# Estoy implementando Equatable en Flutter y me da el siguiente error

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Classes can only extend other classes.
Try specifying a different superclass, or removing the extends clause.

Comment: Asegúrate de que el import de Equatable esté en la clase del CounterCubit